# looping through json array in c#

Tags: c#, json, parsing

I have a json string like,

```
{"objectType" : "Subscriber", "objectList":[{"firstName":"name1","email":"email@example.com","address":"exampleAddress"},{"firstName":"name2","email":"email2@example.com","address":"exampleAddress2"}]}
```

I need to parse it in my C# code. I have tried,

```
JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
object routes_list = json_serializer.DeserializeObject(myjson here);
```

But i cant loop through the "objectList" array. How it can be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11132288/iterating-over-json-object-in-c-sharp

Comment: Can you show your `TargetType` please

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
var jsonObj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<RootObj>(json);
foreach (var obj in jsonObj.objectList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj.address);
}


public class ObjectList
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
}

public class RootObj
{
    public string objectType { get; set; }
    public List<ObjectList> objectList { get; set; }
}
```

Hint: You can use [this site](http://json2csharp.com/) to convert your json string to c# classes

**EDIT**

using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

```
dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

foreach (var obj in jsonObj.objectList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj.address);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Its working fine. Is it possible to work without the class ObjectList and RootObj?

Comment: Do i need to add any dll for that?

Comment: @WingsOfFire Yes the link is in the answer. My favorite json parser.

Comment: What about Newtonsoft.Json?

Answer (score 4):

```
var routes_list = (Dictionary<string, object>)json_serializer.DeserializeObject(myjson);

foreach (var record in routes_list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(record);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, converts to JSON to YAML essentially

```
    string JSONDeserialized {get; set;}
    public int indentLevel;

    private bool JSONDictionarytoYAML(Dictionary<string, object> dict)
    {
        bool bSuccess = false;
        indentLevel++;

        foreach (string strKey in dict.Keys)
        {
            string strOutput = "".PadLeft(indentLevel * 3) + strKey + ":";
            JSONDeserialized+="\r\n" + strOutput;

            object o = dict[strKey];
            if (o is Dictionary<string, object>)
            {
                JSONDictionarytoYAML((Dictionary<string, object>)o);
            }
            else if (o is ArrayList)
            {
                foreach (object oChild in ((ArrayList)o))
                {
                    if (oChild is string)
                    {
                        strOutput = ((string)oChild);
                        JSONDeserialized += strOutput + ",";
                    }
                    else if (oChild is Dictionary<string, object>)
                    {
                        JSONDictionarytoYAML((Dictionary<string, object>)oChild);
                        JSONDeserialized += "\r\n";  
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                strOutput = o.ToString();
                JSONDeserialized += strOutput;
            }
        }

        indentLevel--;

        return bSuccess;

    }
```

usage

```
        Dictionary<string, object> JSONDic = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

          try {

            JSONDic = js.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(inString);
            JSONDeserialized = "";

            indentLevel = 0;
            DisplayDictionary(JSONDic); 

            return JSONDeserialized;

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "Could not parse input JSON string";
        }
```