# How to split the json into space delimited string?

Tags: c#

I wanted to split the result of my jsonData by using space delimited string but I don't know how to do it.

Here is my code on storing my OptionCode jsonData:

```
 if (mappedResult.OptionCodes != null)
  {
     AddJsonVehicleOptionEquip("OptionCodes", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mappedResult.OptionCodes));
  }
```

Here is my viewModel for OptionCodes:

```
 public class DecodedOptionCodesModel
    {
        public string OptionCode { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my code on getting the OptionCode on the third-party ChromeDataHandler :

```
 vehicle.OptionCodes = res.factoryOption?.Select(c => new DecodedOptionCodesModel
            {
                OptionCode = c.oemCode
            });
```

The result of the above code is :

```
[
    {
        "OptionCode": "996"
    },
    {
        "OptionCode": "99T"
    },
    {
        "OptionCode": "44P"
    },
    {
        "OptionCode": "44W"
    },
    {
        "OptionCode": "610A"
    },
    {
        "OptionCode": "613A"
    },
    {
        "OptionCode": "618A"
    },
    {
        "OptionCode": "710A"
    },
```

I wanted the result to be like this:

OptionCode : 996 99T 44P 44W

Comment: Use a JSON-parser instead. Doing this yourself will soon become a nightmare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", vehicle.OptionCodes));
```

Once you split using space delimeter, you can use it the way you want.

[Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55792995/how-to-split-the-json-into-space-delimited-string) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

using [Json.Net](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=json)

```
dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(c.oemCode);

foreach (var obj in jsonObj.objectList)
{
   if(obj.OptionCode.ToString().Trim().Length ==0) continue;
   OptionCode += " " + obj.OptionCode;
}
OptionCode = OptionCode.Trim();
```

Also have a look at: [looping through json array in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646451/looping-through-json-array-in-c-sharp)

Comment: but how to check and not include if the Optioncodes are null because when I check the result, it leave s SPACE for null values on Optioncodes..