# How to read JSON response?

Tags: c#, json, httpresponse, json-deserialization

I have an API which validates the cellphones and returns a JSON data. Now I want to **read the JSON** and show in a table format.

API Call,

```
protected void CallAPI()
{
    WebClient wsClient = new WebClient();
    string url = apiUrl;
    string response = string.Empty;
    string serialkey = txtserialNumber.Text;
    WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(@"https://alt.computechsos.com/api/v1/xx");
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("username:@password"));
    HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    WebHeaderCollection header = resp.Headers;
    string responseText = string.Empty;
    var encoding = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII;
    using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), encoding))
    {
       responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

}
```

The 'responseText' now contains the following `JSON`

**Json returned Response:**

```
{"ios_info":{"serialNumber":"F2LLMBNJXXXQ","imeiNumber":"0138840041323XX","meid":"","iccID":"890141042764009604XX","firstUnbrickDate":"11\/27\/13","lastUnbrickDate":"11\/27\/13","unbricked":"true","unlocked":"false","productVersion":"7.1.1","initialActivationPolicyID":"23","initialActivationPolicyDetails":"US AT&T Puerto Rico and US Virgin Islands Activation Policy","appliedActivationPolicyID":"23","appliedActivationDetails":"US AT&T Puerto Rico and US Virgin Islands Activation Policy","nextTetherPolicyID":"23","nextTetherPolicyDetails":"US AT&T Puerto Rico and US Virgin Islands Activation Policy","macAddress":"ACFDEC6C9XXX","bluetoothMacAddress":"AC:FD:EC:6C:98:8B","partDescription":"IPHONE 5S SPACE GRAY 64GB-USA"},"product_info":{"serialNumber":"F2LLMBNJXXXQ","warrantyStatus":"Apple Limited Warranty","coverageEndDate":"11\/25\/14","coverageStartDate":"11\/26\/13","daysRemaining":"528","estimatedPurchaseDate":"11\/26\/13","purchaseCountry":"United States","registrationDate":"11\/26\/13","imageURL":"http:\/\/service.info.apple.com\/parts\/service_parts\/na.gif","explodedViewURL":"http:\/\/service.info.apple.com\/manuals-ssol.html","manualURL":"http:\/\/service.info.apple.com\/manuals-ssol.html","productDescription":"iPhone 5S","configDescription":"IPHONE 5S GRAY 64GB GSM","slaGroupDescription":"","contractCoverageEndDate":"11\/25\/15","contractCoverageStartDate":"11\/26\/13","contractType":"C1","laborCovered":"Y","limitedWarranty":"Y","partCovered":"Y","notes":"Covered by AppleCare+ - Incidents Available","acPlusFlag":"Y","consumerLawInfo":{"serviceType":"","popMandatory":"","allowedPartType":""}}}
```

How to read this JSON and show data in table format?

Comment: Use Json.NET and create objects that map to the data then just deserialize into the objects.

Comment: any sample plz with reference to above json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Json-Net](http://james.newtonking.com/json) to deserialize the response. To generate classes, you can use [this generator](http://json2csharp.com) which takes a `Json` input and outputs the C# classes associated.

```
    //....
    var responseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseText);
}

public class IosInfo
{
    public string serialNumber { get; set; }
    public string imeiNumber { get; set; }
    public string meid { get; set; }
    public string iccID { get; set; }
    public string firstUnbrickDate { get; set; }
    public string lastUnbrickDate { get; set; }
    public string unbricked { get; set; }
    public string unlocked { get; set; }
    public string productVersion { get; set; }
    public string initialActivationPolicyID { get; set; }
    public string initialActivationPolicyDetails { get; set; }
    public string appliedActivationPolicyID { get; set; }
    public string appliedActivationDetails { get; set; }
    public string nextTetherPolicyID { get; set; }
    public string nextTetherPolicyDetails { get; set; }
    public string macAddress { get; set; }
    public string bluetoothMacAddress { get; set; }
    public string partDescription { get; set; }
}

public class ConsumerLawInfo
{
    public string serviceType { get; set; }
    public string popMandatory { get; set; }
    public string allowedPartType { get; set; }
}

public class ProductInfo
{
    public string serialNumber { get; set; }
    public string warrantyStatus { get; set; }
    public string coverageEndDate { get; set; }
    public string coverageStartDate { get; set; }
    public string daysRemaining { get; set; }
    public string estimatedPurchaseDate { get; set; }
    public string purchaseCountry { get; set; }
    public string registrationDate { get; set; }
    public string imageURL { get; set; }
    public string explodedViewURL { get; set; }
    public string manualURL { get; set; }
    public string productDescription { get; set; }
    public string configDescription { get; set; }
    public string slaGroupDescription { get; set; }
    public string contractCoverageEndDate { get; set; }
    public string contractCoverageStartDate { get; set; }
    public string contractType { get; set; }
    public string laborCovered { get; set; }
    public string limitedWarranty { get; set; }
    public string partCovered { get; set; }
    public string notes { get; set; }
    public string acPlusFlag { get; set; }
    public ConsumerLawInfo consumerLawInfo { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public IosInfo ios_info { get; set; }
    public ProductInfo product_info { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: another option is to iterate the JObject, such as in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11132288/iterating-over-json-object-in-c-sharp

Comment: Yes but it is less performance friendly and more error-prone. I like to use this method for testing APIs but I wouldn't implement it for production code.

Comment: You could also use [JsonProperty] attribute in your models. This way you can correctly name your attributes, while ensuring the correct values are mapped.

Comment: hi @Max after downloading the said file from Json-Net. I got lots of files in folder.I have added reference to my project with name 'Newtonsoft.Json.dll' and added namespace 'using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;' but i am getting error at 'Newton Json.JsonConverter does not contain defination for 'Deserialize' at line  var responseObject = JsonConvert.Deserialize<RootObject>(responseText); :( plz help..

Comment: Oh..! Really great @Max it worked without any error now! Realy realy thanks..:) u saved my day..! I appreciate your efforts towards this post :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to have a class with all the properties which your json string contains , say for example you have that class called Jsondeserial

```
JsonDeserial obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonDeserial>(jsonstring);
```

this will convert your json string to that object values