# Iterating a JSON object array name value pair in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, dynamic, undefined

I've taken this example from a similar question here:

[Iterating over a JSON object (NOT an array) in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42544062/iterating-over-a-json-object-not-an-array-in-c-sharp)

But my data format is a little different, it has array brackets.

As pointed out I can have an undefined number of entries, I want to walk through the entries and extract the data structure into an array/list of objects based on the class defined.

```
{
  "-KeArK3V02mXYWx2OMWh" : [{
    "Description" : "this is a description",
    "Location" : "Atlanta",
    "Name" : "Event One",
    "Time" : "2017-03-01T21:53:12.924645Z"
  }],
  "-KeAtCNF_rmewZ_U3PpH" : [{
    "Description" : "another description",
    "Location" : "Charlotte",
    "Name" : "Event Two",
    "Time" : "2017-03-01T22:01:25.603547Z"
  }],
  "-KeAtd8CQW_EfH3Sw4YQ" : [{
    "Description" : "description goes here",
    "Location" : "Toronto",
    "Name" : "Event Three",
    "Time" : "2017-03-01T22:03:19.3953859Z"
  }]
}
```

and I have a class called Event that is defined as follows

```
class Title {
  public string Description { get; set; }
  public string Location { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public DateTime Time { get; set; }
}
```

The answer given there (which I thought was correct) isn't working

```
Dictionary<string, Title> elist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Title>>(jsonString);
```

It gives me an error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Title' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
>   Path '-KeArK3V02mXYWx2OMWh', line 2, position XX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with structure of Json. Your json has format like Key and value but value is array as per json format. You have to do following thing.

```
Dictionary<string,Title[]> elist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Title[]>>(jsonString);
```

Above solution is simplest one.

Second solution. ( You have to modify as your need but current json will work)

```
 public class TitleConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            JArray jObject = JArray.Load(reader);

            Title title = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Title>(jObject[0].ToString());
                return title;
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            if (objectType.Name == "Title")
                return true;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Now use like this.

```
Dictionary<string,Title> elist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Title>>(jsonString,new TitleConverter());
```

Comment: Right under my nose and I missed it. I guess I was thrown off because if I wrote a class (for test purposes say TClass) with members `public Title X; public Title y; public Title z;` and passed this to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TClass>(jsonString)` it works, I didn't have to define a array in the class. I wonder why that worked?

Comment: Also oddly if I use `List<KeyValuePair<string, Title[]>>` instead of `Dictionary`, it doesn't work. Any idea why (same error of JSON array). I need to maintain the order.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am missing something, you linked a question titled **"Iterating over a JSON object (NOT an array) in C#"**

However your JSON clearly contains an array, you even notice that yourself:

> "But my data format is a little different, it has array brackets."

So you simply need to change you `Title` to an array of Title (`Title[]`):

```
Dictionary<string, Title[]> elist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Title[]>>(jsonString);
```

If you look at your json you can clearly see its defined as an array of objects (look at the '[' and ']'):

```
"-KeAtd8CQW_EfH3Sw4YQ" : [{
    "Description" : "description goes here",
    "Location" : "Toronto",
    "Name" : "Event Three",
    "Time" : "2017-03-01T22:03:19.3953859Z"
}]
```

Comment: Any idea why `List<KeyValuePair<string, Title[]>>` doesn't work instead of a `Dictionary`? I need to preserve the insertion order.