# c# Query path for Firebase data through FirebaseDatabase.net

Tags: c#, firebase, asp.net-core, firebase-realtime-database, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm having trouble figuring out how to query for a 3rd parties data. Here's how it's structured

> /bucketa/bucketb/bucketc/someguidtypekey/anotherguidtypekey/(fields I
>   want to map here)

I've tried this:

```
var stats = await firebase.Child("bucketa/bucketb/bucketc").OnceAsync<WrapperClass>();
```

Where `WrapperClass` is a Key/Object combo, then THAT object is another Key/Object combo, and then that object is the actual class.

```
public class WrapperClass
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public WrapperClass2 Stats { get; set; }
}

public class WrapperClass2
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public RealClass Stats { get; set; }
}

public class RealClass
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
    public string Field3 { get; set; }
    public string Field4 { get; set; }
}
```

I've also tried:

```
var stats = await firebase.Child("bucketa/bucketb/bucketc/*/*").OnceAsync<RealClass>();
```

But that just returned a string of the object type.

Can anyone help out here?

This is in `C#`, using `FirebaseDatabase.net`

**Edit:**

All right, now we are getting closer. Implementing @ElmarJensen fix (from one of his comments):

```
...OnceAsync<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, RealClass>>>();
```

I'm now getting the error:

> Error converting value True to type
>   'RealClass'

In the error, it says it's trying to convert `RealClass.property1` where `property1` is of type `bool`.

Why is it trying to convert the `property1` to my `RealClass` object type instead of the parent object? The structure makes sense to me. And in the exception, the "responseData" property has all of the records that I expected in the correct JSON format, so not sure what's going on here.

**Edit 2:**
Here's the actual data format:

```
{
    "0M6bRFLLokR6sIJAcKFN6y91NXB3": {
        "-KYdDf62eQUMGb-ov737": {
            "somethingBoolean":true,
            "asdf":"Joe User",
            "oasdfasdfsad": {
                "firstName":"asdf",
                "lastName":"asdfasdf",
                "tasdfme":"Wasdfh",
                "teasdfore":6,
                "teaasdfme":"SDFO"
            },
            "fasdfewaef":0,
            "startedAt":1.481381640492956E9,
            "updatedAt":1.481381687802693E9,
            "wfefeaefw":"182",
            "asdf": {
                "firstName":"asdf",
                "lastName":"asdf",
                "asdf":"asdfasdfasdf",
                "teamScore":0,
                "asefeawfawef":"DFDFSWEF"
            },
            "aefawefawefawefawef":0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this: [Retrieving Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wildcards ("bucketa/bucketb/bucketc/*/*") do not exist like that in Firebase, so if you have no influence on the datastructure, you're stuck with downloading the full data tree at once from the root at "bucketa/bucketb/bucketc". The problem is that for firebase-database-dotnet, the "children" of this tree (someguidtypekey/anotherguidtypekey) will appear as properties of the object with the GUIDkey as the property name - which means that you need to know the guidkeys at compile time for this to work. However, given that the method uses JSON.net under the hood, and that library supports deserializing into Dictionaries instead of objects as well, the following may actually work:

```
await firebase.Child("bucketa/bucketb/bucketc").OnceAsync<Dictiona‌​ry<string, Dictionary<string, RealCl‌​ass>>>();
```

Also, if it is only one query, it would be fairly easy to do this "manually" with a HttpClient, or use FireSharp (another FB .net library, https://github.com/ziyasal/FireSharp) that allows you easy direct access to the "raw" returned JSON, like this:

```
FirebaseResponse response = await client.GetAsync("bucketa/bucketb/bucketc");
var myJson = response.Body;
```

After that, you can easily iterate the properties of the returned json object (e.g. [Iterating over JSON object in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11132288/iterating-over-json-object-in-c-sharp#11132348)).

Of course, if you had direct control over the datastructure, the advise would be to further flatten it (see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data).

I am not entirely sure what you mean by "But that just returned a string of the object type." `.OnceAsync<RealClass>();` will return a collection of objects of type FirebaseObject (the original object is exposed as its Object property) - never a String.

**Reply to update**

It sounds as if your query goes one layer deeper than I assumed from you data description. Would this work?

```
await firebase.Child("bucketa/bucketb/bucketc").OnceAsync<Dictiona‌​ry<string, RealCl‌​ass>>();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just so I'm clear, I see you're saying I can't do the wildcard approach, but is it still possible to do it by defining the class with the 2 wrapper classes around it like you're stating here: "the "children" of this tree (someguidtypekey/anotherguidtypekey) will appear as properties of the object with the GUIDkey as the property name". So I would get back an array of `WrapperClass` objects, where I could then flatten that array down to the `RealClass` level. This is the ONLY data I need, so I'm ok with developing something specifically for this data structure.

Comment: The problem is that the children will not appear as an array or dictionary object (with key-value-pairs), but as hard-coded property names that you have to know at compile time. This means that you could only do it if you know all the "someguidtypekey" and "anotherguidtypekey" values at compile time. However, if you have that list it would be much easier to iterate it and query each path separately (using `var stats = await firebase.Child("bucketa/bucketb/bucketc/key1/key2").OnceAsync<RealClass>();`).

Comment: Once I receive back that data though, couldn't I just iterate over all keys in the dictionary item, and flatten that way? Like this: `foreach(var item in myDictionary.Keys)
{
  foreach (var innerItem in item.Keys) { flattenToThisObject(innerItem); }
}` (I'm not at home so can't test/PoC this yet...)

Comment: Seeing how the "OnceAsync" function is implemented (using Newtonsoft JSON.net - which supports serializing to Dictionaries), I suddenly realize that the following may actually work in your case:
`await firebase.Child("bucketa/bucketb/bucketc").OnceAsync<Dictionary<Dictionary<RealClass>>>();`

Comment: Oh boy, that would be fantastic. I'll confirm this afternoon/tonight!

Comment: And to reply to your comment: the problem is that you won't get a "myDictionary", only a simple object with lots of properties. E.g., if /bucketa/bucketb/bucketc/a1453/b347/ would exist, you'd need to go to myObject.a1453.b347 to get the values - there is no myObject["a1453"].["b347"].

Comment: Ah, now I understand, it wouldn't have the generic property name "key", it would be "a1453".......thanks for bearing with me until I followed you.

Comment: Made  a small change to code -> code should have been `await firebase.Child("bucketa/bucketb/bucketc").OnceAsync<Dictiona‌​ry<string, Dictionary<string, RealCl‌​ass>>>();`

Comment: Didn't get a chance to try it last night, will definitely check tonight.

Comment: Hey Elmar, we are getting closer, see my edit to the original question.

Comment: Not sure why that worked (removing 1 level of dictionary), but it did. I'll update my question with the REAL structure, with actual values taken out.