# Split string with multiple json strings

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to split a c# string that has multiple json strings in it

Example:

```
{"id":0,"username":"test"}{"id":8,"username":"testuser"}
```

How can I loop through each json string in its own 'foreach' loop

Comment: You should just deserialize it.

Comment: you can replace }{ with }|{ and split | and put in foreach

Comment: That isn't valid JSON. Does your data really look like that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11132288/iterating-over-json-object-in-c-sharp

Comment: If it is JSON it is not just a string - it is serialized data.  Deserialize or parse it.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli How is it not valid?

Comment: I found an existing answer here: [What is the correct way to use JSON.NET to parse stream of JSON objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26601594/7586). This question is not about parsing a valid JSON array, but about parsing concatenated JSON documents. You may not like it, but this is a real format being used (for example by mongoexport).

Comment: @Jacob Go to jsonlint.com and paste that string in.

Answer (score 1):

hi you can do some trikk on invalid json...

```
string myinvalidJson = "{\"id\":0,\"username\":\"test\"}{\"id\":8,\"username\":\"testuser\"}";

foreach(var item in myinvalidJson.Replace("}{", "}|{").Split('|')) {
...
}
```

or create valid json and deserialize with newtonsoft

```
string myinvalidJson = "{\"id\":0,\"username\":\"test\"}{\"id\":8,\"username\":\"testuser\"}";

var validJson = "[" + myinvalidJson.Replace("}{", "},{") + "]";
```

Comment: How is it invalid? I have it parsed in php online which prints to site just the string as I have shown then i use "string json = *opens link and grabs site data*

Comment: @Jacob if you have array of object you it must be in brace [] and also between all object must be camma like [ {"a":10}, {"a":20} ] ... you can test your json string with this site : https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 1):

You may Deserialize it  into array of structure type using `Newtonsoft.Json`
to do this you need to have a string matching an array of JSONs like below:

```
"[{\"id\":0,\"username\":\"test\"},{\"id\":8,\"username\":\"testuser\"}]"
```

next lets have strucure type called 'User' like below:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username{ get; set; }  
}
```

finally do Deserialize:

```
string str = "[{\"id\":0,\"username\":\"test\"},{\"id\":8,\"username\":\"testuser\"}]";
User[] res = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User[]>(str);
```

Now you are able to do 'foreach' loop on `res` array.