# How to sort a JObject by value

Tags: c#, json, sorting, json.net

I have some JSON:

```
{
    "AI": "1",
    "AJ": "0",
    "AM": "0",
    "AN": "0",
    "BK": "5",
    "BL": "8",
    "BM": "0",
    "BN": "0",
    "BO": "4",
    "CJ": "0",
    "CK": "2"
}
```

I'd like to sort it by number, highest to lowest, and get the property with the highest number by just writing the first index of the JSON.  Can you help me?

This is what I have so far:

```
string voteJson = File.ReadAllText("vote.json");
Object voteObj = JObject.Parse(voteJson);

//How to sort the object here?

//Saving it 
string output = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(voteObj, 
    Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
File.WriteAllText("vote-sorted.json", output);
```

Comment: That's an object.  It doesn't have indexes, and its values aren't ordered.  JSON defines an object as:  "An object is an **unordered** set of name/value pairs."

Comment: This is not a "// fill in some good code here" site  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: I searched for hours now, I just cant find any soting functions or something simmilar. I started writing C# 2 Days ago and just need help. This is the only code site I knew so I'm here to ask...

Comment: This is not a tutorial site.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: As pointed by @Amy, you cannot sort json objects directly.
The only thing you can do is transfer it to an list of pair and then sort it.
Or better, you just iterate through the pairs of the json object and keep track of the highest one to avoid multiple loops. For iterating over a JSON object, refer to the [solution offered there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11132288/iterating-over-json-object-in-c-sharp).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although the [JSON spec](https://www.json.org/) defines a JSON object as an unordered set of properties, Json.Net's [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) class does appear to maintain the order of properties within it.  You can sort the properties by value like this:

```
JObject voteObj = JObject.Parse(voteJson);

var sortedObj = new JObject(
    voteObj.Properties().OrderByDescending(p => (int)p.Value)
);

string output = sortedObj.ToString();
```

You can then get the property with the highest value like this:

```
JProperty firstProp = sortedObj.Properties().First();
Console.WriteLine("Winner: " + firstProp.Name + " (" + firstProp.Value + " votes)");
```

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dptrZQ