# How to iterate through the following json using c#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I want to get all the results from the below json:

```
[
  {
    eventID: 1,
    name: 'Wedding',
    status: true
  },
  {
    eventID: 2,
    name: 'Baptism',
    status: true
  },
  {
    eventID: 3,
    name: 'Tour',
    status: true
  },
  {
    eventID: 4,
    name: 'Birthday',
    status: null
  }
]
```

I tried to parse using `var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);` but get an error. My code only works if there is a single set of values in the JSON. Can anyone please help?

Comment: this is not valid JSON

Comment: Convert it to list and then you can simply iterate using foreach

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating over JSON object in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11132288/iterating-over-json-object-in-c-sharp)

Comment: try var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json); here T is your object type

Comment: Your JSON is an array, not an object, so use `JArray.Parse(json)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you fix your Json - those elements need to be in an array (i.e surrounded by square brackets).

Given you have this class:

```
public class Data 
{
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool? Status { get; set; }
}
```

You can deserialize your Json using [Json.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/):

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Data>>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you care about adhering to .net property naming standards, you can define a type for your object

```
private class DeserializedObject
{
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool? Status { get; set; }
}
```

Then using Json.net, you can deserialize it using

```
var _deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DeserializedObject[]>(Data, new JsonSerializerSettings {ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()});
```

If you aren't into following .net conventions,

```
private class DeserializedObject
{
    public int eventID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool? status { get; set; }
}
```

and deserialize it using

```
var _deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DeserializedObject[]>(Data);
```

where your json is defined as

```
private const string Data = "[{eventID: 1,name: 'Wedding',status: true},{eventID: 2,name: 'Baptism',status: true},{ eventID: 3,name: 'Tour',status: true},{eventID: 4,name: 'Birthday',status: null}]";
```

Answer (score -1):

The Json you are provided here is not valid so I am assuming you have a json like below

```
string jsonString = "{'data':[{'eventID':1,'name': 'Wedding','status': true},{'eventID':2,'name': 'Baptism','status': true},{'eventID':2,'name': 'Birthday','status': null}]}".Replace("'", "\"");
```

Then you have to create an appropriate model to hold the data.

```
 public class ConvertedResult
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "data")]
        public IEnumerable<JsonConvertSampleClass> ResultList { get; set; }
    }

    public class JsonConvertSampleClass
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "eventID")]
        public int EventId { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "status")]
        public bool? Status { get; set; }
    }
```

Then finally `Deserialize` your `Object`

```
 var response = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConvertedResult>(jsonString);
```

So the var response(type of `ConvertedResult`) will contain a list of Type `JsonConvertSampleClass` with 3 items in it.

Note : Do not forget to include `using Newtonsoft.Json;`

**Question is edited after the answer posted so, answer for the edited question :**

```
      string jsonString = "[{'eventID':1,'name': 'Wedding','status': true},{'eventID':2,'name': 'Baptism','status': true},{'eventID':2,'name': 'Birthday','status': null}]".Replace("'", "\"");

   var response = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<JsonConvertSampleClass>>(jsonString);
```

Side note : If you don't want to use `JsonProperty` Attribute then you can go for `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` as @Fram suggested.

Comment: The user doesn't need all those JsonProperty attributes.  Just change the JsonSerializerSettings ContractResolver to the Camel Case resolver and it will work.  They OP also does not need to change the JSON string.  deserialize as an array of whatever type they define

Comment: @Fran that is one alternative thats all. is there anything wrong in this solution ?And why the negative vote?

Comment: You didn't answer the OP's question because you changed his json when it was valid as is. Then proceeded to add the JsonProperty attribute to every property when simply swapping out the contract resolver would achieve what the OP wanted.

Comment: @Fran The question is edited there after it seems , The Json was not valid and not proper when I answered the question, that is why i have created a json using the inputs the questioner provided. Please check the comments in the question. Later point the questioner has edited the question i guess, now only I have noticed that.

Comment: @Fran are you still thinking that my answer needs a negative vote ?